# How to Update database with tk entries

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I'm trying to update a database with entries. But if put something in, nothing happens in my database and ttk treeview. In this example is my primary key `id`  and `self.parent.optionbar.person[0].get()`.

```
    def update_personen(self):
        personen = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", host="127.0.0.1", database="PersonHobbyStadt")
        cur_personen = personen.cursor()

        self.selected = self.parent.main.person_tree.focus()
        self.values = self.parent.main.person_tree.item(self.selected, text="", values=(
                                                        self.parent.optionbar.person[0].get(),
                                                        self.parent.optionbar.person[1].get(),
                                                        self.parent.optionbar.person[2].get(),
                                                        self.parent.optionbar.person[3].get(),))

        cur_personen.execute("UPDATE person SET vorname=%s, nachname=%s, geburtstag=%s WHERE id=%s",
                             (
                                 self.parent.optionbar.person[0].get(),
                                 self.parent.optionbar.person[1].get(),
                                 self.parent.optionbar.person[2].get(),
                                 self.parent.optionbar.person[3].get(),

                             ))

        print(self.parent.optionbar.person[3].get())

        personen.commit()
        personen.close()
```

any suggestions?

here to see what i mean. On top left the 4 entries.
[image]

Comment: did you print self.parent.optionbar.person[3] if it contains 2, update will only execute when it finds a corre4spsonding row(s).

Comment: yes. I tested it. It prints me out the birthday. In the treeview it works. I think something is wrong with the syntax. But here I don't get any errors, so I'm wondering

Comment: Does this all happen in one click? Is there a refresh button that refreshes the entries in treeview for you to see it changed?

Comment: the syntax looks ok, but you should enable the general log and see what actually reaches your database and id can't be a birthday to may collisions

Comment: The update in the treeview works if i click on the button (in the screenshot after `+` `-`  the third one). If I Insert new data I see it in the treeview and in Mysql. With Insert I havent any problems. I use for the update the same entries.

Comment: I updated the question with the treeview if it needed.

Comment: @nbk ok thanks for the hint. I put `self.parent.optionbar.person[0].get()`  after `self.parent.optionbar.person[3].get()` now it works. i forget where my ID in the entry lists is .....